# Snmp translate for CommonObjs?

Tags: snmp, net-snmp, mib, snmpd

Tring to go through new mib i added to mibs file, i have run this command as a test

```
snmpwalk -v3 -u  $USER-l authPriv -a SHA -A "$PASS" -x AES -X $PASS 10.x.x.x panCommonMib
```

and i think it made the walk on the entire PAN-COMMON-MIB which is good, but some objects there are understandable like

```
PAN-COMMON-MIB::panSysSwVersion.0 = STRING: x.1.x
```

And i can translate and know what this obj do.
And some are like that:

```
PAN-COMMON-MIB::panCommonObjs.7.4.4.1.6.6 = INTEGER: 0
PAN-COMMON-MIB::panCommonObjs.7.5.1.1.201 = STRING: "Log Collector"
PAN-COMMON-MIB::panCommonObjs.7.5.1.2.0 = ""
PAN-COMMON-MIB::panCommonObjs.7.5.1.2.101 = ""
```

If i try to translate them it gives the textual translate of : panCommonObjs

```
snmptranslate -IR -Td -OS PAN-COMMON-MIB::panCommonObjs.7.4.4.1.6.6

PAN-COMMON-MIB::panCommonObjs.7.4.4.1.6.6
panCommonObjs OBJECT-IDENTITY
  -- FROM       PAN-COMMON-MIB
  DESCRIPTION   "
                        Sub-tree for common MIB objects."
::= { iso(1) org(3) dod(6) internet(1) private(4) enterprises(1) panRoot(25461) panMibs(2) panCommonMib(1) panCommonObjs(2) 7 4 4 1 6 6 }
```

I want to understand what is
`INTEGER: 0` is, how can i translate this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe your MIBs are outdated.

```
snmptranslate -IR -Td -OS PAN-COMMON-MIB::panCommonObjs.7.4.4.1.6.6
PAN-COMMON-MIB::panDeviceLoggingExtFwdStatsTable1minAvgSendRate.6
panDeviceLoggingExtFwdStatsTable1minAvgSendRate OBJECT-TYPE
  -- FROM   PAN-COMMON-MIB
  SYNTAX    Unsigned32
  MAX-ACCESS    read-only
  STATUS    current
  DESCRIPTION   "Counter for average send rate over 1 minute interval."
::= { iso(1) org(3) dod(6) internet(1) private(4) enterprises(1) panRoot(25461) panMibs(2) panCommonMib(1) panCommonObjs(2) panDeviceLogging(7) panDeviceLoggingExtFwd(4) panDeviceLoggingExtFwdStatsTable(4) panDeviceLoggingExtFwdStatsEntry(1) panDeviceLoggingExtFwdStatsTable1minAvgSendRate(6) 6 }
```

I got them from [github](https://github.com/librenms/librenms/tree/master/mibs/paloaltonetworks)